# JavaScript regex - null argument makes the regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex to be used with JavaScript. When testing I came across some strange behavior and boiled it down to the following:

```
/^[a-z]/.test("abc"); // <-- returns true as expected
/^[a-z]/.test(null);  // <-- returns true, but why?
```

I was assuming that the last case was going to return `false` since it does not meet the regex (the value is null and thus, do no start with a character in the range). So, can anyone explain me why this is not the case?

If I do the same test in C#:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z]");
var res = regex.IsMatch(null); // <-- ArgumentNullException
```

... I get an `ArgumentNullException` which makes sense. So, I guess when testing a regex in JavaScript, you have to manually do a `null` check?

I have tried searching for an explanation, but without any luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `test` converts its argument : `null` is converted to the `"null"` string.

You can check that in the console :

```
/^null$/.test(null)
```

returns `true`.

The call to `ToString(argument)` is specified in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.6.2) (see also [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8)).

Comment: It makes me very sad that this is the right answer.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen for more, see wtfjs.com

Comment: Spot on, thanks! This also makes me panda sad, but I guess that's the way it is. While @AmitJoki answer also addresses my question, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer because you were first to respond and has included links to the spec. Thanks.

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse I *love* Pandas! So don't be sad and go on! :)

Comment: this is the quintessential Javascript behavior

Answer (score 9):

Here `null` is getting typecasted to `String` form which is `"null"`.

And `"null"` matches your provided regex which is why it is evaluating to `true`

In Javascript, everything(or mostly) is an `Object` which has `ToString` method which will be automatically called upon *internally* in case there is a need for a typecast.